# ClassNotFoundException:XMLGregorianCalendar, Maven dependencies are downloaded successfully, but not recognized ,

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-11

I am using java 11 , maven version 3.6 and Spring Boot. I am having a problem running a unit
test due to  error below:

```
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$3.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:288) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator$3.run(ReflectionNavigator.java:285) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:285) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.nav.ReflectionNavigator.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionNavigator.java:64) ~[jaxb-core-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findFieldProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:380) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:311) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeClassInfoImpl.getProperties(RuntimeClassInfoImpl.java:186) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:261) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:103) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:227) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:98) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:375) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:390) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:465) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:303) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1156) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:165) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.0-b170127.1453.jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:297) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:286) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:409) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:721) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:662) ~[jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromPackages(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:569) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:502) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:476) ~[spring-oxm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XMLGregorianCalendar
```

I know that in java 11 the java.xml.bind is removed, and for this reason i have added in my pom.xml file the dependencies

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I checked the jars downloaded from in maven dependcies and javax.xml.datatype is present. Like below:
[image]

Why is this happening? How it is possible that the `XMLGregorianCalendar` class is not recognized even thought id downloaded ? What can I do to fix this problem?

I have tried to run :

- `mvn clean compile`
- `mvn clean install`
- I executed a maven project update from eclipse

None of the action above worked.

Below it the result from running the command `mvn dependency:tree`

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:3.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.0-b170127.1453:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.7.8:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.13:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:transport:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-core:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-secure-sm:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-x-content:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-smile:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.9.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers-common:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-backward-codecs:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-join:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queryparser:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial-extras:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial3d:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-suggest:jar:7.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-cli:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- com.tdunning:t-digest:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- org.elasticsearch:jna:jar:4.5.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:reindex-client:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:lang-mustache-client:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- com.github.spullara.mustache.java:compiler:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:percolator-client:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.plugin:parent-join-client:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:rank-eval-client:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.elasticsearch.plugin:transport-netty4-client:jar:6.4.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.29.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:rest:jar:5.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpasyncclient:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore-nio:jar:4.4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.elasticsearch.client:sniffer:jar:5.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-jcs-jcache:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-jcs-core:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.11.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.11.1:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.13.Final:test
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:test
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] +- com.github.javafaker:javafaker:jar:0.16:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:android:1.20:test
[INFO] |  \- com.github.mifmif:generex:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO] |     \- dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8:test
[INFO] \- com.devskiller:jfairy:jar:0.6.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:test
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:24.0-jre:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.codehaus.mojo:animal-sniffer-annotations:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:test
[INFO]    +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:jar:4.2.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.iban4j:iban4j:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.14:test
```

Comment: From memory, is ClassNotFoundException thrown when there is any problem loading the class (often static initializer hitting an exception) - so this can be different to NoClassDefFoundError which is where there is no class definition to load from

Comment: Yes, you are right, the issue is ClassNotFoundException, I edited the title of question according the exception

Comment: I'm still a bit puzzled then, so I think the class definition is probably found by the class loader but it fails to load it. I did have a quick look at the class when I was at my laptop, and didn't see a static initializer there, mind you I forgot to check to see if there are any static members, maybe with initial values that cause a problem? I guess I'd maybe stick a (conditional) breakpoint in the ClassLoader to see what happens when it tries to load XMLGregorianCalendar

Comment: I put a breakpoint on ClassLoader.loadClass, but didn't enter, it failed with same error

Comment: This sounds like a slightly horrible problem then. Looking again at your stacktrace, I *guess* that one of the declared fields is of type XMLGregorianCalendar and then it is the native method that is having trouble which is why you wouldn't hit a breakpoint. Not sure how a native method could get hit by a ClassNotFoundException - outside the bounds of my knowledge and unfortunately this would be a slightly painful problem to reproduce unless you can pull together a very minimal piece of code to reproduce the issue. I'll let you know if I think of anything

Comment: thanks Chris for your time

Comment: Is this maybe an old version? because u have `xml-apis-1.4.01.jar` and in your pom you refer another version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Welcome to jar hell" should be the title of this question.

You have stated correctly that javax.xml.bind module is removed from java 11 and it is also deprecated in java 9 and java 10.
You have correctly replaced the missing dependency from the removal of `javax.xml.bind` module with the following:

```
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I created a new maven project and added the above dependencies. I was able to successfully run the project with a
variable of the declared type of `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar`.

I think you don't need the `xml-apis`, that comes as a transitive dependency of `dom4j`. I think that if you remove
`xml-apis` from dom4j, the problem will be fixed. Do the modification below:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
         <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If `dom4j` is a transitive dependency for some other dependency you have in your pom, then you should find first which dependency has `dom4j` as a transitive dependency. And after that you should make the following modification:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>{the dependency group id that has dom4j as transitive dependency}</groupId>
   <artifactId>{the dependency artifact that has dom4j as transitive dependency}</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
         <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Explanation**

I think that this problem has risen from dependencies having the same artifact and different group id and maven is not able to distinguish them.
`xml-apis` artifact can be from the `xerces` organization or from `xml-apis` organization like below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
<artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
<version>1.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Although they have the same artifact, maven does not recognize them as the same because they have different group id. This does not cause conflict and both dependencies are included as resolved dependencies.
My advice is, exclude the `xml-apis` from `dom4j` and update the project.

I hope this helps you solve the issue.

Comment: I was struggling with a similar problem for days, removing the xml-apis helped solve the problem. I can't believe everything is working. thank you